# Dynamically changing the size of a <div> element

Tags: javascript, html, function, if-statement

I'm trying to resize a `<div>` when the function is called from this if statement. I know the `if` statement is working because when the function `mTr()` is called it works and I know the function `myFun()` works but for some reason the function myFun() isnt getting called.

```
if (window.screen.height==568) { // iPhone 4"
    document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]").content="width=320.1";
    myFun("divId");
    mTr();

}
function myFun(id)
{
    var obj = document.getElementById(id);
    if (obj)
    {
        obj.setAttribute("style", "height:300px;");
    }
}
function mTr()
{
    alert("Hello World!");
}
```

Comment: So, what is the question?

Comment: why the function myFun isn't getting called

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons that `myFun()` wouldn't be getting called:

1. `window.screen.height` is not exactly 568
2. `document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]").content="width=320.1";` generates a script error that causes script execution to stop
3. There is some error before this code that causes execution to stop
4. Your code is executing too early before the DOM has been loaded and thus it can't find the relevant DOM elements.

The first thing to do is to examine your browser error console and see what script errors (if any) are reported.

The second thing to do it to set a breakpoint on the `if` statement in your javascript debugger (built into most browsers) and then step through each of the following statements to see what is happening.

You can also embed `console.log("xxx")` statements in your code to create a breadcrumb trail in the console to tell you what's going on.

Answer (score -1):

I retested everything.  I think I found your problem. You had an error in your code.

**Error was here:**

```
document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]").content="width=320.1";
```

**Instead, it should be:**

```
document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]").setAttribute('content', 'width=320.1');
```

**Complete Javascript:**

```
if (window.screen.height==568) { 

   document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]").setAttribute('content', 'width=320.1');    
   myFun("divId");
   mTr();
}

function myFun(id)
{
   var obj = document.getElementById(id);
   if (obj)
   {
       obj.setAttribute("style", "height:300px;");
   }
}

function mTr()
{
   alert("Hello World!");
}
```

You can test it out here:
http://jsfiddle.net/KwGwd/

Comment: In JavaScript, doing `if(object)` evaluates to true as long as the object isn't null.